# How can I determine what percentage of Github projects contain unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, github, github-api

I'm working on a presentation about unit testing and TDD. One statistic I'd like to share is the percentage of Github projects that contain unit tests. Is this data available somewhere?

If not, is it possible to obtain through a Github API? I was considering a simple file-based approach based on project type (see if a Java project has any files ending in `Test.java`, or `spec.rb` for Ruby), but I've never used their API and don't know how feasible this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any API to provide you with that information.
Or at least not without browsing the entire set of repositories, which would not be practical anyway. You might want to suggest the github staff to conduct such a survey themselves, but that will be up to them :)

Answer (score 1):

Grab the list of Java repositories from the Github API (use `search` and the `language` parameter), then clone each repository, look for `Test.java` or whatever and collect your results. I don't think there's a way of doing this without cloning each project though.

Comment: I ended up going this route - I put up some code to check for any files that ended in `test` or `spec`. I wrote up my answer here: http://matthewsteele.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/town-tester/